# PayPal cURL login no longer functioning as of a month ago

Tags: php, curl, paypal

A freelance coder wrote some custom PHP cURL for me a couple of months ago to log into my business PayPal account and print shipping labels via Canada Post.

As of roughly one month ago, the login process started failing.  See code below.  It fails the sanity check every single time.  One day this code worked, the next day no dice.  The coder cannot find the source of the problem.  Can anyone here see anything wrong with this code?

```
////
// 1. INITIALIZE

cp_progress(1, 'Initializing');

if (file_exists(PAYPAL_COOKIE_FILE)) {
unlink(PAYPAL_COOKIE_FILE); // delete old cookie file
}

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);  //Windows 2003 Compatibility 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.0.10) Gecko/2009042523 Ubuntu/9.04 (jaunty) Firefox/3.0.10');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, PAYPAL_COOKIE_FILE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, PAYPAL_COOKIE_FILE);

////
// 2. LOG IN

cp_progress(2, 'Logging in');

$response = cp_get_page($ch, 'https://www.paypal.com/ca/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ship-now');
// echo '<br /><br /><br /><br /> Response = ',$response,'<br /><br /><br /><br />'; // exit;

cp_sanity_check($response, '<title>Login - PayPal</title>');

$matches = '';
// preg_match("/<form method=\"post\" name=\"login_form\" target=\"paypal\" action=\"([^\"]*)\"/siU", $response, $matches);
preg_match("/<form method=\"post\" name=\"login_form\" action=\"([^\"]*)\"/siU", $response, $matches);
$form_action = $matches[1];

$matches = '';
preg_match("/<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"CONTEXT_CGI_VAR\" name=\"CONTEXT\" value=\"([^\"]*)\"/siU", $response, $matches);
$form_context = $matches[1];

// echo "form_action = $form_action<br>";
// echo "form_context = $form_context<br>";

/*$query_string = "CONTEXT=$form_context&login_email=" . PAYPAL_EMAIL . "&login_password=" . PAYPAL_PASSWORD
. "&login_cmd=&login_params=&submit.x=Log%20In&operating_system=Linux&form_charset=UTF-8&browser_name=Firefox&browser_version=3";*/  

$query_string = "CONTEXT=$form_context&login_email=" . PAYPAL_EMAIL . "&login_password=" . PAYPAL_PASSWORD
. "&login_cmd=&login_params=&submit.x=Log%20In&operating_system=Windows%2NT&form_charset=UTF-8&browser_name=Firefox&browser_version=19";
// echo '$form_action = ',$form_action;
// echo '$query_string = ',$query_string; exit;
$response = cp_post_page($ch, $form_action, $query_string);
// echo '<br /><br /><br /><br /> Response = ',$response,'<br /><br /><br /><br />'; // exit;

cp_sanity_check($response, '<title>Canada Post - Create Your Shipping Label - PayPal</title>');

$matches = '';
preg_match("/<form method=\"post\" name=\"shippingForm\" action=\"([^\"]*)\"/siU", $response, $matches);
$form_action = $matches[1];

$matches = '';
preg_match("/<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"CONTEXT_CGI_VAR\" name=\"CONTEXT\" value=\"([^\"]*)\"/siU", $response, $matches);
$form_context = $matches[1];

$matches = '';
preg_match("/<input name=\"auth\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"([^\"]*)\"/siU", $response, $matches);
$form_auth = $matches[1];

// echo $form_auth; exit;
////
```

Comment: What's in `$response` when you get it back from PayPal?

Comment: As far as i know PayPal ware changing their systems and have released a new API https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/

Comment: Bonus comment: disabling SSL verification is _NOT_ a "Windows 2003 Compatibility" thing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paypal has updated the fields in this login page. Replace code:

```
$matches = '';
preg_match("/<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"CONTEXT_CGI_VAR\" name=\"CONTEXT\" value=\"([^\"]*)\"/siU", $response, $matches);
$form_context = $matches[1];

// echo "form_action = $form_action<br>";
// echo "form_context = $form_context<br>";

/*$query_string = "CONTEXT=$form_context&login_email=" . PAYPAL_EMAIL . "&login_password=" . PAYPAL_PASSWORD
. "&login_cmd=&login_params=&submit.x=Log%20In&operating_system=Linux&form_charset=UTF-8&browser_name=Firefox&browser_version=3";*/  

$query_string = "CONTEXT=$form_context&login_email=" . PAYPAL_EMAIL . "&login_password=" . PAYPAL_PASSWORD
. "&login_cmd=&login_params=&submit.x=Log%20In&operating_system=Windows%2NT&form_charset=UTF-8&browser_name=Firefox&browser_version=19";
```

with:

```
//changed

$matches = '';
preg_match("/<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"CONTEXT_CGI_VAR\" name=\"CONTEXT\" value=\"([^\"]*)\"/siU", $response, $matches);
$form_context = html_entity_decode($matches[1]);


$matches = '';
preg_match("/<input name=\"auth\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"([^\"]*)\"/siU", $respone, $matches);
$form_auth = urlencode($matches[1]);

//echo "form_action = $form_action<br>";
//echo "form_context = $form_context<br>";

$query_string = "CONTEXT=$form_context&login_email=" . PAYPAL_EMAIL . "&login_password=" . PAYPAL_PASSWORD
            . "&login_cmd=&login_params=&submit.x=Log%20In&operating_system=Linux&form_charset=UTF-8&browser_name=Firefox&browser_version=3&auth=$form_auth";
//end changed
```

You are adding a new `preg_match` line and `$form_auth`

Comment: Many, many thanks for this helpful answer.  The application is up and running again and my life is simplified again!